# node.js process.env doesnt work with PUSH

Tags: node.js

try to attach a env variable in process.env object and found it doesnt work with push operation. I have tired
for example:

```
    process.env.kk = []
    process.env.kk.push(1)

    exception:
    process.env.kk.push is not a function
```

can anyone explain this issue? thanks

Answer (score 1):

`process.env` variable aren't JS variables, they're used globally throughout the system, and dont support array's etc.

when you run `process.env.kk = []`

`[]` is returned, however if you then call for the variable you'll see:

`''` as the response.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) :

> Every assignment to a `process.env` key will be converted to a string.

The array will be converted to empty string if it doesn't have any items.

```
λ ◆ node -e 'process.env.a = ['1','2']; console.log(process.env.a);'
1,2
```

Or the items itself will be converted into a string.